# SMS receive with no notification android 4.4.2

Tags: android, notifications, sms

I want to receive a sms in my app, but I don't want my Android to show a notification about that event.

i was declare

```
<receiver android:name="mypackage.SMSReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
   </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

written code

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    Object[] pdus = (Object[])extras.get("pdus");
    for (Object pdu: pdus)
    {
      SmsMessage msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdu);

      String origin = msg.getOriginatingAddress();
      String body = msg.getMessageBody();

      // Parse the SMS body
      if (isMySpecialSMS)
      {
        // Stop it being passed to the main Messaging inbox
        abortBroadcast();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and try set priority

```
<intent-filter android:priority="100">
```

But not work!Phone display notification!

have Android 4.4.2 (API 19) (Samsung Note 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with KitKat (4.4), your app will need to be the default SMS app in order to suppress Notifications, as the default app is responsible for issuing them. Attempting to abort the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast no longer works. Any attempt to abort that broadcast is ignored by the system. Furthermore, the default app listens for the `SMS_DELIVER` broadcast, which cannot be aborted either, as it is delivered to only the default app. You can consult the following link for information on making your app eligible to be a default SMS app.

[Getting Your SMS Apps Ready for KitKat](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html?m=1)